# Is it possible to convert .ppt file to .pptx without using interop or Spire?

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

Is it possible to convert .ppt file to .pptx without using interop or Spire, because I think it will be something like converting a binary file to open xml format?

Public void ConvertPPTToPPTX(MemoryStream pptFileInput,MemoryStream pptxFileOutput){

.....

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this programmatically you will have to use interop or some third party library.

If you can use interop you will get the fidelity of Office, any other third party library is just a best effort, unless it uses interop under the hood, which some do. Make sure you check if the library requires Office to be installed.

There is nothing built in directly to the .NET framework if that is what you are asking. 
Neither will Microsofts **OOXML SDK** support conversion

The only thing I know of from Microsoft that will do PPT conversion is 
**PowerPoint Automation Services** , but this requires access to a SharePoint Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179894(v=office.15).aspx

This is not an easy problem to solve, in order to do a conversion you have to understand and be able to read in the PPT Binary FileFormat

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313106(v=office.12).aspx

And then translate that all to the OOXML File format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926741(v=office.12).aspx

All while taking into account the thousands of features the file format supports, the differences in the file formats,the features that are not documented well, and the ones that are documented incorrectly.

What exactly are you trying to solve? A one time conversion, a batch conversion, as needed? Maybe we can provided some other suggestions with more details.

Comment: I am using interop before and it runs smoothly converting PowerPoint presentations(.ppt - with 5 to 10 slides) into .pptx. But as the number of slides increase I am having this error 

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Comment: A one time conversion

Comment: It sounds like you might be running out of memory or are having a permissions issue, make sure your instances of powerpoint are being correctly cleaned up after each execution.